# Combobox model setselecteditem

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, selection, jcombobox

I have got the following code:

```
package nypdapp;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CaseFileAddFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form CaseFileFrame
     */
    private Connection Econn;
    private int cfid;
    private boolean wijzig;
    private DefaultListModel DetectiveListModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private DefaultListModel EmployeeTotListModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private DefaultListModel WitnessModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private DefaultListModel EvidenceModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private DefaultListModel SuspectsModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private DefaultComboBoxModel DistrictModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    private DefaultComboBoxModel LocationModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    SpinnerModel spmodel = new SpinnerNumberModel(2013,1950,2013,1);
    public CaseFileAddFrame(int cfid, boolean wijzig) {
        initComponents();
        this.cfid = cfid;
        this.wijzig=wijzig;
        s1.setVisible(false);
        s3.setVisible(false);
        s4.setVisible(false);
        YearSn.setModel(spmodel);
        try
        {
            SimpleDataSource.init();
            Econn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
        }
        catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        setDistricts();
        getSelectedDistrict();
        ClassCB.setEnabled(false);
        if(wijzig == true)
        {
            setInformation();
        }        
    }

    private void setLocation(int lid)
    {
        try
        {
            Statement userStat = Econn.createStatement();
            String userquery = "SELECT name, district_name FROM location l INNER JOIN district d ON l.distr_ic = d.district_id WHERE l_id = "+lid;
            ResultSet result = userStat.executeQuery(userquery);
            result.next();
            String name = result.getString("district_name");
            System.out.println("DBName: "+name);
            int i = DistrictModel.getSize();
            for(int p =0; p < i; p++)
            {
                System.out.println("Current:"+DistrictModel.getElementAt(p));
                if(DistrictModel.getElementAt(p).equals(name))
                {
                    //DistrictModel.setSelectedItem(p);
                    DistrictCB.setSelectedIndex(p);
                    System.out.println("Done<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }         
    }
   private void setInformation()
    {
        try
        {
            Statement userStat = Econn.createStatement();
            String userquery = "SELECT * FROM casefile WHERE cf_id = "+this.cfid;
            ResultSet result = userStat.executeQuery(userquery);
            result.next();
            switch(result.getInt("crime")) 
            {
                case 0: 
                {
                    CrimeCB.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
                    break;
                case 1: 
                {
                    CrimeCB.setSelectedIndex(1);
                }
                    break;
                case 2: 
                {
                    CrimeCB.setSelectedIndex(2);
                }
                    break;
                default: 
                {
                    CrimeCB.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
            }
            if(CrimeCB.getSelectedIndex() == 2)
            {
                ClassCB.setEnabled(true);
            switch (result.getInt("classtype")) 
            {
                case 0: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
                    break;
                case 1: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(1);
                }
                    break;
                case 2: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(2);
                }
                    break;
                case 3: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(3);
                }
                    break;
                case 4: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(4);
                }
                    break;
                case 5: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(5);
                } 
                    break;
                case 6: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(6);
                }
                    break;
                case 7: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(7);
                }
                    break;
                case 8: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(8);
                }  
                    break;
                default: 
                {
                    ClassCB.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
            }
            }
            else
            {
                ClassCB.setEnabled(false);
            }

            switch (result.getInt("type")) 
            {
                case 0: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
                    break;
                case 1: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(1);
                }
                    break;
                case 2: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(2);
                }
                    break;
                case 3: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(3);
                }
                    break;
                case 4: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(4);
                }
                    break;
                case 5: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(5);
                } 
                    break;
                case 6: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(6);
                }
                    break;
                case 7: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(7);
                }
                    break;
                case 8: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(8);
                }       
                    break;
                default: 
                {
                    TypeCB.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
            }
            SubjectTF.setText(result.getString("subject"));
            Date date = result.getDate("date");
            int month = date.getMonth();
            int day = date.getDate();
            int year = date.getYear()+1900;
            MonthCB.setSelectedIndex(month);
            DayCB.setSelectedIndex(day);
            spmodel.setValue(year);
            AssignedDATF.setText(result.getString("assignedDA"));
            FRNameTF.setText(result.getString("fr_id"));
            DescriptionTA.setText(result.getString("description"));
            setLocation(result.getInt("lid"));
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }       
    }    
    private void setDistricts()
    {
        try
        {
            Statement userStat = Econn.createStatement();
            String userquery = "SELECT district_id, district_name FROM district";
            ResultSet userResult = userStat.executeQuery(userquery);
            while(userResult.next())
            {
               int ids = userResult.getInt("district_id");
               String name = userResult.getString("district_name");
               DistrictModel.addElement(new DistrictItem(name,ids));
            }
            DistrictCB.setModel(DistrictModel);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }                                              

    private void SubmitCaseFileButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
        if(validation() == false)
        {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WARNING\nCheck the field validation!\nIf there is no Assigned DA Enter 'Unknown'");
        }
        else if(wijzig == false)
        {
            int crime = CrimeCB.getSelectedIndex();
            int crimeclass;
            if(ClassCB.isEnabled() == true)
            {
                crimeclass = ClassCB.getSelectedIndex();
            }
            else
            {
                crimeclass = 0;
            }
            String subject = SubjectTF.getText();
            int month = MonthCB.getSelectedIndex()+1;
            int day = DayCB.getSelectedIndex()+1;
            int year = Integer.parseInt(spmodel.getValue().toString());
            Date date = ToSQLClass.toSqlDate(year, month, day);
            int crimetype = TypeCB.getSelectedIndex();
            LocationSItem li = (LocationSItem)LocationCB.getSelectedItem();
            int locationid = li.id;
            String assignedDA = AssignedDATF.getText();
            String description = DescriptionTA.getText();
            String fr = FRNameTF.getText();
            try
            {
                PreparedStatement addstat = Econn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO casefile VALUES(cf_id,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                addstat.setString(1, subject);
                addstat.setInt(2, crime);
                addstat.setInt(3, crimetype);
                addstat.setString(4, description);
                addstat.setString(5, assignedDA);
                addstat.setString(6, fr);
                addstat.setNull(7,java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
                addstat.setDate(8, date);
                addstat.setInt(9, crimeclass);
                addstat.setInt(10, locationid);
                addstat.execute();    
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WARNING\nCasefile added!\n\nDon't forget to add suspects, witnesses, detectives and evidence!");
                this.dispose();
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int crime = CrimeCB.getSelectedIndex();
            int crimeclass;
            if(ClassCB.isEnabled() == true)
            {
                crimeclass = ClassCB.getSelectedIndex();
            }
            else
            {
                crimeclass = 0;
            }
            String subject = SubjectTF.getText();
            int month = MonthCB.getSelectedIndex()+1;
            int day = DayCB.getSelectedIndex()+1;
            int year = Integer.parseInt(spmodel.getValue().toString());
            Date date = ToSQLClass.toSqlDate(year, month, day);
            int crimetype = TypeCB.getSelectedIndex();
            LocationSItem li = (LocationSItem)LocationCB.getSelectedItem();
            int locationid = li.id;
            String assignedDA = AssignedDATF.getText();
            String description = DescriptionTA.getText();
            String fr = FRNameTF.getText();
            try{
            Statement addstat = Econn.createStatement();            
            addstat.executeUpdate("UPDATE casefile SET subject = '" + subject
                       + "' ,assignedDA = '" + assignedDA
                       + "' ,description = '" + description
                       + "' , fr_id = '" + fr
                        +"',date = '"+date
                        +"' ,crime = "+crime
                        +" ,crimeclass = " +crimeclass
                        +" ,crimetype = " +crimetype
                        +" ,lid = " +locationid
                       + " WHERE cf_id = " + this.cfid);         
            }
            catch(SQLException e) { System.out.println(e); }
        }
    }                                                                                           
    private void getSelectedDistrict()
    {
        try
        {
            LocationModel.removeAllElements();
            DistrictItem di = (DistrictItem)DistrictCB.getSelectedItem();
            Statement userStat = Econn.createStatement();
            String userquery = "SELECT l_id, name FROM location WHERE distr_ic = "+di.id;
            ResultSet userResult = userStat.executeQuery(userquery);
            while(userResult.next())
            {
               int ids = userResult.getInt("l_id");
               String name = userResult.getString("name");
               LocationModel.addElement(new LocationSItem(ids,name));
            }
            LocationCB.setModel(LocationModel);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    private void DistrictCBItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
        getSelectedDistrict();
    }                                           

    private void CrimeCBItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                         
        if(CrimeCB.getSelectedIndex() == 2)
        {
            ClassCB.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            ClassCB.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }                
}
```

The DistrictModel contains every district retrieved from the setDistricts() method.

I think it is pretty self explanatory what it does. Thing is, it never enters the if-statement (even though it prints all items in de districtmodel.getelementat) so it does run correctly through the for loop.

Comment: Then it means that none of the element of the model is equal to the name retrieved from the database. Please respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Well what it does is it gets the element at p and checks if that equals to the db retrieved name.. So it runs through ALL element-possibilities right?

Comment: Right. This is what I'm saying. If it does through all the elements, and if `Done<<<` is never printed, that simply means that none of the elements in the model is equal to the name.

Comment: Alright, thanks. But how is that possible? Because one element in that model must equal the name. The model has a-d names, and lets say the name is a..

Comment: It's impossible to know with the code you posted. Step through the program using a debugger, or add traces to understand.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: How can set the selected item that has the name (text on it) with the name from the DB?

Comment: It's impossible to say with the code you posted. We don't know what the model contains (type and value of the elements). We don't know what the name is.

Comment: Let's say the model contains the letters A,B,C,D. And the name in the DB is C. The prints all read A B C D, and of course C twice because of the first print. Again, it does not go into the if-statement.

Comment: Why don't you post your code, the exact type and value of every element in the model, and the exact value of the name retrieved from the DB? That would help you and us identifying the problem. Maybe you don't store Strings in your model. Or maybe there is a hidden space somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The answer is simple now that we can see the code. The district model contains instances of `DistrictItem`:

```
DistrictModel.addElement(new DistrictItem(name,ids));
```

And you compare every element of this model with a String. So obviously, the comparison will always be false, because a DistrictItem can't be equal to a String. Only a String can be equal to a String.

So, assuming the district names are unique (but you should probably use the ID rather than the name), you should iterate through the elements and find the one which has the same name as the one you retrieved:

```
int i = DistrictModel.getSize();
for (int p = 0; p < i; p++) {
    DistrictItem currentDistrictItem = (DistrictItem) DistrictModel.getElementAt(p);
    if (currentDistrictItem.getName().equals(name)) {
        DistrictCB.setSelectedIndex(p);
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, you should respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lwoercase letter: `districtModel` instead of `DistrictModel` (and same for all the other variables)